# I'm looking for a batch script that appends the names of multiple text files to the first line of each file

Tags: windows, bash, file, batch-file, evernote

I have a folder that contains more than 200 text file (.txt)

I want an easy way to add each file name to the first line of each file.

example I have a file called `"I am a file.txt"` with the following content:

```
"
I am line one
I am line two
"
```

this should become something like this:

```
"
I am a file
=====
I am line one
I am line two
"
```

I'm wondering if someone could help me build a batch script that does that.

*the reason for that is I want to upload all my text files to Evernote. But Evernote doesn't read the file name, instead it name the note as the first line in the text.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That worked for me:

(just past this in a file called whatever.bat and run it)

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F IN ('dir /b /s "C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\myDir\*.txt"') do (
  (
    echo %%~nF
    echo ___________________________
    type "%%F"
  )>"%%F.new"
  move /y "%%F.new" "%%F"
)

pause
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
pushd "pathToYourFolder"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do (
  (
    echo %%F
    echo =====
    type "%%F"
  )>"%%F.new"
  move /y "%%F.new" "%%F"
)
```

Comment: There must be something missing I've replaced "pathToYourFolder" with "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\TESTING"
I'm getting:
The system cannot find the file *.txt

Comment: Yes, there is something missing :-)  That error message means `"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\TESTING"` does not contain any `*.txt` files.

Comment: Are you kidding me!!!
I have 10 files in that folder and all of type Text Document (.txt)
I even putted that batch file inside the folder and still getting the same error.
Have you test this code on your machine?

Comment: @MahmoudZalt - OMG, I just realized I had a stupid bug. My FOR loop was a complete failed cross between an ordinary FOR and a FOR /F. Sorry about that. It should be fixed now.

Comment: @MahmoudZalt - and now I see you posted a corrected version of my original code before I did. Good job, and +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the filenames are passed as arguments to the script, you could use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$@"
do
   sed -i "1 i ${file%.*}\n=====" "$file"
done
```

Assuming of course you have `sed` available, but since you have tagged the question with `bash` I imagine you have Cygwin installed.

Comment: Or, perhaps more likely that bash was a mistake and the OP meant batch, to go along with Windows.

Comment: Or that too yes, although batch-file is there. Should have looked more carefully at the tags before answering.

Comment: it doesn't matter if its `bash` or `batch`. Its still alright just for knowledge, not just for the OP but for others browsing SO. what's the fuss anyway.